# How to force-reload a Python module after pip upgrade?

Tags: python, module, reload, python-importlib

In practical applications, certain Python packages need to be upgraded dynamically during runtime. And to avoid service interruption, the main Python process shall not be terminated and relaunched due to individual module upgrade. To re-import the upgraded module, we typically use `importlib.reload()`. However, it does not work. To illustrate the problem:

Firstly, we run `pip install yt-dlp==2023.3.3` to installed the old version `yt-dlp`, then run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pip, sys, importlib, time

import yt_dlp
print('before update:')
try:
    yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
    pass

pip.main(['install', 'yt-dlp==2023.3.4'])

from importlib import reload
reload(yt_dlp)

print('after update:')
try:
    yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
    pass
```

The output is shown below:

```
before update:
2023.03.03
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting yt-dlp==2023.3.4
  Using cached yt_dlp-2023.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (1.45.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (3.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (1.0.9)
Installing collected packages: yt-dlp
  Attempting uninstall: yt-dlp
    Found existing installation: yt-dlp 2023.3.3
    Uninstalling yt-dlp-2023.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled yt-dlp-2023.3.3
Successfully installed yt-dlp-2023.3.4
after update:
2023.03.03
```

Even after `pip` successfully upgraded `yt-dlp` to Version 2023.3.4 and `yt_dlp` has been reloaded by `importlib.reload()`, it still shows the old version 2023.03.03 . And if you check `yt-dlp` version now (either by running `pip freeze | grep yt-dlp` or `yt-dlp --version`), it is indeed the upgraded version 2023.3.4 (will change as new version emerges).

What is ridiculous and sarcastic about the current Python 3 `importlib.reload()` implementation is that the following piece of code actually works without using importlib at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pip, sys

def cleanse_modules(name):
    for module_name in sorted(sys.modules.keys()):
        if module_name.startswith(name):
            del sys.modules[module_name]
    del globals()[name]


import yt_dlp
print('before update:')
try:
    yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
    pass

pip.main(['install', 'yt-dlp==2023.3.4'])

cleanse_modules('yt_dlp')

import yt_dlp

print('after update:')
try:
    yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
    pass
```

The output is shown below:

```
before update:
2023.03.03
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting yt-dlp==2023.3.4
  Using cached yt_dlp-2023.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (1.45.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (3.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.4) (1.0.9)
Installing collected packages: yt-dlp
  Attempting uninstall: yt-dlp
    Found existing installation: yt-dlp 2023.3.3
    Uninstalling yt-dlp-2023.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled yt-dlp-2023.3.3
Successfully installed yt-dlp-2023.3.4
after update:
2023.03.04
```

The output is correct and as expected. Therefore, a natural question that arises is that: how can the native Python 3 library function does not work while in principle it is possible to get this working using manual Python code?

Comment: This kind of thing is basically doomed. Making module reloading actually work consistently would probably take a major ground-up overhaul of the entire Python language. `importlib.reload` is basically only useful for *extremely* simple interactive use cases, and even then, it's a huge source of confusion and problems.

Comment: If you want to be able to upgrade packages without service interruption, you're probably better off designing your service to be able to seamlessly launch a new process (potentially in a different venv, or on a different machine, to avoid affecting packages the old process is using) and transfer operation to the new process, instead of trying to reload modules in a running process.

Comment: Note that your `cleanse_modules` thing doesn't really work either - code that already imported the old version of the module will continue using the old version unless that code manually re-imports the module, plus old instances of classes defined in the module will continue using the old versions of those classes. Also, the `startswith` check can end up purging more than a package and its submodules - for example, if you've got unrelated packages `ham` and `hamster`, purging `ham` will purge both.

Comment: Hope I'm not introducing noise on the comments: maybe you should try containers. You can have a container with the new version and switch the connection to the new container. Also deployment software can handle this, installing the new version and make the switch.